# HTML code - Direct to individual URL after user choice

Tags: javascript, html

Please find the code I'm working on with working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mfuusp9p/551/

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
<select name="optone" id="stateSel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select size</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select name="opttwo" id="countySel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select size first</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select name="optthree" id="citySel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select back wall first</option>
</select>
```

There are 3 combo boxes with variations. When the last selection is made I'm trying to get it to direct the user to a URL.

For example, IF size:3000mm x 3000mm AND no side walls AND no back walls THEN go to google.com

And so on for every variation (48 in total).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For redirection in javascript you use :

```
window.location = "https://google.com";
```

Comment: Thanks - so to make it load a page on selection would this work`window.onload = function(){
    if (citySel.value = 'Salinas') {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    } else {
        window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
    }
};`

Comment: Your function must be like this :  `var ddl = document.getElementById("citySel");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "Salinas")
   {
   window.location.href = "http://www.google.com" ; } else { window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com" ; } `